# Issue regarding a responsive script I'm creating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build I responsive script for my future projects to use and develop along the way, ever since I don't like how the automated responsive scripts mess up my designs.

The idea about this script is that it redirects you to another version of the website or just load another CSS file that matches some of the common resolutions.

Let me first attach my code so you get a better idea about the issues I'm facing.

```
/*Change CSS and also redirect the page in response to common resolutions.*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    checkWidth ();
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
var xFullPath = window.location.pathname;
var xPageName = xFullPath.substring(xFullPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

function checkWidth(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
        cssLocation = $('link[href$="main.css"]');

    if (windowWidth <= 240){
        cssLocation.attr('href','stylesheets/240-main.css');
        }
    else if (windowWidth <= 490){
        if (xPageName != "smartPhone-index.html"){
            window.location.replace("smartPhone-index.html");
            }
            cssLocation.attr('href','stylesheets/480-main.css');
        }       
    else if (windowWidth <= 768){
        if (xPageName != "index.html"){
            window.location.replace("index.html");
            }
            cssLocation.attr('href','stylesheets/768-main.css');
        }       
    else if (windowWidth <= 1024){
        if (xPageName != "index.html"){
            window.location.replace("index.html");
            }
        cssLocation.attr('href','stylesheets/1024-main.css');
        }       
    else if (windowWidth >= 1280){
        if (xPageName != "index.html"){
            window.location.replace("index.html");
            }
        cssLocation.attr('href','stylesheets/1280-main.css');
        };  
    };
```

This script is working as I expected, when I re-size my browser it starts to perform as I wished, yet I'm facing 2 problems.

1- When I uploaded a static website to a server just for the sake of testing the script yes it works when I re-size, but when I opened that address with my smart-phone, it just load the default one which is the 1024*768, and yes the phone do it's smart stuff with dealing with these common websites, but why it didn't work?...

2- When I re-size the browser and it reaches the point where it don't just load another CSS but it redirect to a different HTML structure page which helps more with phones etc, around 490px if I stopped there it keeps reloading the page, nonstop, until I drag it more inside maybe when it reaches 480px it stops and put you where you should.

How to fix these issues, or can you show me some guide lines to follow?

Thank you all.

Comment: Use Bootstrap? The CSS takes care of this for you in Bootstrap.

Comment: Not sure why you would need Javascript for this since it can be easily accomplished with CSS media queries. I'll second George's suggestion which is to use something like Bootstrap or Foundation.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Thank you for the delightful answer, though I'm not a fan of the based on float dynamics, as I said before, it messes up my designs.

Comment: @APAD1 I feel grateful for you kind answer, though CSS media queries are not supported by old browsers, and I would still use JavaScript to redirect visitors to another HTML page.

Comment: With shims/polyfills you can get support for media queries all the way back to IE7. I just finished a website in Foundation that works perfectly in IE7/8.

Comment: @APAD1 Thank you again for the amazing answer, you really expanded my globe with the shims/polyfills fix, never thought that it could fix this issue. Though, I'm getting what I want with the redirect and CSS switches, I just want to know why it didn't work on smart-phones? And I will still use the JavaScript in order to redirect to another HTML page. Right?

Comment: Have you tried to invert sign? <= convert to >= (and for the first one just < 490 ) So < 490 , >= 490 , >= 768 - etc... And as APAD1 say there're polyfills and library you can use, such as http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq